# Is mobile-phone speech-recognition geographically/dialect weighted?

Tags: speech-recognition

When I pronounce the English word "sir" as it is pronounced [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=sir%20pronunciation%20in%20english&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&oq=sir%20pronunciation%20in%20english&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.79924911j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which is American English (at least when I visit that page) my mobile phone thinks I'm saying the name "Sarah" when it is in dictation mode in the messaging app.

I am curious if speech-recognition algorithms used in the major mobile phones are geographically/dialect weighted. I know there are some English dialects where the final -r- sound is pretty much left off, and the duration of the word is much briefer than it is in most American English dialects.